# Unexpected end of JSON input Ajax php

Tags: php, ajax

I am getting the following error when making an AJAX call on my web hosting service:

```
Status: parsererror: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

This script works fine local testing using XAMPP, returns data with no issues. There are a few buttons that the user can press, which at the point of time will make an AJAX call. Some of the functions work fine, others don't appear to return anything once these scripts are running on our web hosting provider.

**This is an example of one of the AJAX calls:**

```
function vesselajax(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'vesselajax.php',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                document.getElementById("vesseltable").innerHTML = '<tr><th>FCM</th><th>Hull ID</th><th>Manu ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Manufacturer</th><th>Length</th><th>Year</th><th>Value</th><th>Owner</th><th>Loss Payee</th><th>Base</th></tr>' + data;
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }  
        });
}
```

**Here is some code from the vesselajax.php**

```
<?php
require 'login.php';
$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pword, $database, 3306);
if ($connection ->connect_error) die($connection ->connect_error);
$query = "select v.vessel_table_id, v.vessel_fcm, v.vessel_hull_id, v.vessel_name, v.vessel_length, v.vessel_manufacturer, v.vessel_manufacturer_id, v.vessel_year, v.vessel_value, o.owner_name, l.loss_payee_name, b.base_name
from vessel v
join owner o
on o.owner_id = v.owner_id
join loss_payee l
on l.loss_payee_id = v.loss_payee_id
join base b
on b.base_id = v.base_id";
$result = $connection->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $counter = 1;
    $data = "";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['vti'] = $row['vessel_table_id'];
        $data .= "<tr><td>". $row["vessel_fcm"]. "</td><td>". $row["vessel_hull_id"]. "</td><td>". $row["vessel_manufacturer_id"]. "</td><td>". $row["vessel_name"]. "</td><td>". $row["vessel_manufacturer"]. "</td><td>". $row["vessel_length"]. "</td><td>". $row["vessel_year"]. "</td><td>". $row["vessel_value"]. "</td><td>". $row["owner_name"]. "</td><td>". $row["loss_payee_name"]. "</td><td>". $row["base_name"]. "</td><td>"."<a href='removevessel.php?vti=".$_SESSION['vti']."'><button type='button' rel='tooltip' title='Remove' class='btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button></a><button name='".$_SESSION['vti']."' id='".$counter."' onclick='editvesselnow(this.name,this.id);' type='button' rel='tooltip' title='Edit' class='btn btn-warning btn-simple btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button>"."</td></tr>";
        $counter++;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "<div class='header'>0 results</div>";
}
$connection->close();
?>
```

Before you mention something about prepared statements, I am just testing at the moment :)

These scripts work fine locally, pulling all of the associated data, but when loaded onto the web environment, the error above is thrown for only a few of these AJAX calls. Most of them are very similar to what I am showing below.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

When the query returns 0 rows, you return HTML instead of JSON. Change

```
} else {
    echo "<div class='header'>0 results</div>";
}
```

to:

```
} else {
    echo json_encode("<div class='header'>0 results</div>");
}
```

It's not clear why you're returning JSON, though. That's normally used for returning arrays and objects, not text or HTML.

Comment: OK, look in the Network tab of the console and check the raw response data, maybe there's something else being returned like an error message.

Comment: Got it to work. Took off encode_JSON and changed the dataType to HTML. So, maybe I am not understanding why it works this way now. I thought JSON data response was a more efficient way to handle the response from AJAX.

Comment: It has nothing to do with efficiency. It's a way to serialize structured data like arrays and objects. It's not needed for strings.

Comment: It seems like the encode_json works up until a certain number of records are being returned. I was able to use this method fine locally testing, but as soon as I deploy to development only dataType: HTML works.

Comment: It's more efficient than XML, which was the previous standard encoding.

Comment: A few weeks ago someone else reported a problem with large JSON responses, it was because there were some special characters later in the array and they were causing an encoding error.

Comment: It was just a coincidence that it worked with small data because it didn't have the special characters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can't think of a reason either. Maybe the server has some type of restriction on the characters.

Answer (score 0):

From my php file I removed:  echo encode_json($data) and switched it to just echo ($data).

Also, in the ajax call, make sure to change the dataType from json to ‘html’